# Orbital change to reach specific earthly location with constrained dV

Tags: orbital-maneuver

If I have an orbit (in this case, a non-eccentric orbit) and, at a specific point in time, need to find a maneuver to cause reentry in a specific point as quickly as possible with a delta-V limit (if such a change exists)... How do I do this?

I’ve used an equation derived, I believe, from Lambert’s equations which will find the required velocity to reach a certain point at a certain time, but I need the direction to burn a specific delta-V to reach the point in the least amount of time. I’m hoping such an equation exists.